# Do action for only switch status for publish_post

Tags: email, publish, post-status

I am creating notification e-mail for approved post. It sends mail to author like 'your post approved'. So i am using `publish_post` filder.

```
function notificationApprove( $ID, $post ) {
    // Send mail
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'notificationApprove', 10, 2 );
```

It works good. But problem is, it sends mail every post saves. I want to send mail for only switch status pending to approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `transition_post_status` hook, which is fired whenever the status is changed. So to perform an action when the status is changed to `publish`, you'd do this:

```
function notificationApprove( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && 'post' === $post->post_type ) {
        // Send mail
    }
}
add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'notificationApprove', 10, 3 );
```

This will only fire when the status changes. This means that if the post is ever unpublished and then republished the notification will be sent again.

If you only ever what the notification to be sent *once*, then you could save a custom field when the notification is sent, then when the post is re-published check if the field already exists and don't send the notification if it does:

```
function notificationApprove( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && 'post' === $post->post_type ) {
        $notification_sent = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'notification_sent', true );

        if ( $notification_sent !== 'sent' ) {
            // Send mail
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'notification_sent', 'sent' );
        }
    }
}
add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'notificationApprove', 10, 3 );
```